# Taylor's expansion of a norm

Tags: real-analysis

I want to Taylor expand (2nd order) the function, $f(x)=e^{{\|x\|}^2}$ (where $x$ is $= (x,y)\in R^2$) and I also want to include the 3rd order integral remainder.

I know that for $e^{x^2}$ I have: $f(x) = e^{x^2} + 2xe^{x^2}(x-x_0) + (2xe^{x^2} + 4x^2e^{x^2})(x-x_0)^2/2$. How does this change when I have the norm and how would I make this expression tidier/simpler.

Also for the integral remainder: I have $E_3(x)=1/6\int_{x_0}^x(x-t)^3f^4(t)dt  $

Again is this correct and how does it change with the norm?

Comment: taylor expand around what point?

Comment: any arbitrary x_0.

Comment: The strategy is to consider the line segment $[x_0,x]\subset\mathbb R^n$ (here $n=2$) parameterised by $\gamma(t) = x_0 + t(x-x_0)$ and then taylor expand the 1D function $ f(\gamma(t))$ at $t=0$.

Comment: After Taylor expanding you should get a polynomial in $x$ with constant coefficients, which your expression is not. Can you find the mistake?